# How to order Solr results by relevance to the input?

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr and I am trying to order the results I get by their relevance to the input keyword.
For example, if I have a field which is the title of a document and I have two documents with the following titles A:"The book of Martin" and B:"The book of Angela", when I search for "book angela" I want B to appear first than A which is not happening. This is the code I have for this case:

```
  <fieldType name="gramText" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

The query I use is "titles:book angela".

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: `titles:book angela` will not search for `book angela` in the `titles` field - it will search for `book` in the titles field and `angela` in whatever field you have defined as the default search field. You might want to try `titles:book titles:angela`, but this will also depend on how the `titles` field is defined. You can append `debug=all` to your query to see exactly how each hit is scored. Giving the most relevant (well, "relevant" is subjective) hit the highest score is the default behavior, so it will depend on the field type and exactly how you're searching (if sorting, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that was the behaviour of the query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the intent of your query is not same as how solr interprets it. Based on your requirement, you should try this -

> title: book OR title: angela